# error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'declarationMap'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint

I recently tried to update my typescript version to 3.3 and added:

```
npm i @microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.3 -D -E.
```

and to my tsconfig:

```
"extends": "./node_modules/@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-2.9/includes/tsconfig-web.json
```

All according to this blog:
https://www.eliostruyf.com/define-the-typescript-version-you-want-to-use-in-sharepoint-framework/

When running my program I get the following error:

```
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'declarationMap'.
```

My tsconfig file looks like this:

```
{
  "extends": "./node_modules/@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-2.9/includes/tsconfig-web.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "inlineSources": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules/@microsoft"
    ],
    "types": [
      "es6-promise",
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "dom",
      "es2015.collection"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "lib"
  ]
}
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test",
    "FIXFIX": "webpack --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/decorators": "1.7.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-application-base": "1.7.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.7.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-dialog": "1.7.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.7.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "^1.7.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.7.0",
    "@pnp/common": "^1.3.9",
    "@pnp/config-store": "^1.3.3",
    "@pnp/graph": "^1.3.9",
    "@pnp/logging": "^1.3.9",
    "@pnp/odata": "^1.3.9",
    "@pnp/pnpjs": "^1.3.3",
    "@pnp/polyfill-ie11": "^1.0.2",
    "@pnp/sp": "^1.3.9",
    "@pnp/sp-clientsvc": "^1.3.3",
    "@pnp/sp-taxonomy": "^1.3.3",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33",
    "@types/react": "16.4.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.0.5",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "luxon": "^1.25.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "16.3.2",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "scriptjs": "^2.5.9",
    "sp-pnp-js": "^3.0.10",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.9.0",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4",
    "@microsoft/generator-sharepoint": "^1.8.2",
    "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.3": "0.9.28",
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.7.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.7.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-tslint-rules": "1.7.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "1.7.0",
    "@types/chai": "3.4.34",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.38",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "tslint-microsoft-contrib": "~5.0.0"
  }
}
```

Anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: did you check your typescript version with `tsc -v` ?

Comment: @XouDo, what version should `tsc -v` return?

Comment: @TerminalVelocity the version of your typescript compiler.  The compiler option may not be available for older verisons.